# Construtor não é iniciado junto com componente no Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, visual-studio-code, construtor, component

Quando eu crio componentes no VS Code, no arquivo Ts, não é criado o construtor e nem o `OnInit` por padrão! Não que atrapalhe, já que eu os crio manualmente, mas é um saco!

Alguém saberia me explicar o motivo e como eu posso corrigir, no caso de ser uma falha ou estar faltando alguma coisa?

Eu os crio com o seguinte comando:

```
ng g c nomeDoComponent
```

Comment: Por favor, esclareça seu problema ou forneça detalhes adicionais a fim de destacar exatamente o que você precisa. Da forma como está escrito atualmente é difícil dizer com exatidão o que você está perguntando.

Answer (score 7):

Não é uma falha. Não gerar o construtor e o `OnInit` foi uma decisão tomada na versão 15.0.0.

- A issue: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/23678
- O commit: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/commit/301b5669a724261d53444d5172334966903078c0

A justificativa deste commit é que a maioria dos usuários preferem adicioná-los manualmente quando necessário.

Até o momento parece não haver opção para gerá-los segundo a documentação: https://angular.io/cli/generate#component

Em 2020 alguém abriu uma issue sobre permitir escolher quais métodos implementar quando gerando um componente, mas foi fechada por "falta de interesse da comunidade", veja: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/18771

Aproveitando... Nesta versão também removeram a criação automática dos `environments.ts` quando vc cria uma nova aplicação. O commit: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/commit/283b564d1de985f0af8c2fcb6192801a90baacda

Então, era necessário criá-los manualmente se quisesse, mas desde a versão 15.1.0, há um schematic que gera o `environments.ts` por  você. Basta executar o seguinte comando:

```sh
ng g environments
```

Comment: vlw cara, sua contribuição para o assunto foi massa.

Comment: Show de bola! Obrigado pelo esclarecimento!